# For what values $p$ does $\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(x)}{1+x^p} dx$ converge.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

**Question:**

> For what values $p$ does $\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(x)}{1+x^p} dx$ converge.

I have been approaching this using parts or substitution but I see no clear path to a solution. What is the best way here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $p>1$ then:
$$\left|\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log x}{1+x^p}\,dx\right|\leq \int_{0}^{1}|\log x|\,dx + \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^p} = 1+\frac{1}{(p-1)^2}. $$

Moreover, in such a case:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log x}{1+x^p}\,dx=\frac{d}{da}\left.\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^a}{1+x^p}\,dx\right|_{a=0} = -\cos\frac{\pi}{p}\cdot\left(\frac{\pi}{p\sin\frac{\pi}{p}}\right)^2.$$

Comment: What technique have you used to split the integral after the first inequality?

Comment: @mathjacks:  $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx + \int_{1}^{+\infty}f(x)\,dx.$$ Taking absolute values: $$\left|\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)\,dx\right|\leq \int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|\,dx + \int_{1}^{+\infty}|f(x)|\,dx.$$ For the very last step, it is useful to recall that integrals like $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^a}{1+x^p}\,dx$$ can be computed through Euler's Beta function. Here, the sine appears as a consequence of the $\Gamma$ reflection formula and the cosine as the derivative of the sine.

Answer (score 1):

Try $x = e^{t}$ to get

$$\int_1 ^\infty \frac{t e^t}{1+e^{tp}} dt = \int_1^\infty \frac{e^{tp}}{1+e^{tp}} \frac{t}{e^{(p-1)t}}.$$
Can yo proceed?

Comment: Great approach! Let me see what I can do...